# how to prevent visibility of header value given in ajax for Authentication

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I'm stuck in security issue, We have using authentication for API's and calling api from client application using ajax. To brake authentication we have passing our base 64 encoded value in header, but it's visible in my script page. So anyone can access my api's using this encoded value.

please help me to hide and use this header value.

```
var data={};        
var setHeader = { 'Authorization': **'Basic QVBJVXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA=='** }
        $http.post(url, data, {
            headers: setHeader
        })
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            callback(data);
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        })
```

Comment: this is not security at all, even if u break word and uglify, for important apis a login process to get a ticket then store to local, like cookie, then use the ticket to authorize. if it is a public api, u can limit frequency( by ip)

Comment: Which system of Authentication do you use?   Bearer tokens?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using "Token"you could consider provide your Authorization "Token" only after authentication and have the connection between client and server using HTTPS, and never rely on base64 for security.

A very simple example of how could work for a Single Page Application Rest API:

- User enter credentials in client app.
- Client app send credentials to server under HTTPS in header.
- Server return to client a "Token" with expiration time.
- Client store "Token" in `localStorage` (or other methods).
- Any subsequent request to API is done using the "Token" passed in header.
- When the "Token" expires, client app need to re-authorize asking credentials to User and getting a new valid "Token" from API.

In this way, the client application store only a valid "Token" and not the real credentials. You could potentially add additional validation logic at server side in order to validate even further your "Token" (like IP validation and so on).

Notes: do not relay on Base64  for security as it is not useful for  encryption. What it does is just encoding, so it is way of representing binary data using only printable (text) characters.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply GibboK, i have tried local storage, but local storage is happen in client machine, if they aware of it, can easily get this key (like from cookie,cache,etc..)

Comment: @Naveenraj of-course if an user know debugger tools in browser can always find out your  key value and use your API with that key. I suggest to have a more advance validation Technics at server side, for example check IP, time, location and device in order to validate your token.

Comment: yes @Gibbok, but this all should be valid, when a user tries to access my api's, right?? Than tracking for each api call from each user is make huge storage in my database.

Comment: @Naveenraj with a Token used in a REST API you need to validate the token in each request. Usually expired tokens are removed from db using at some time interval.

Comment: so before expiring between the time any one can access right?? thanks for understood my problem. please guide me to complete this fix this issue.

Comment: @Naveenraj correct. After an user get a token passing valid credentials, the token is valid (until its expiration time) so with a valid Token an User can access the API. You can read more information searching on SO or Google for "Token-based security in a REST API". I hope it helps. If you found my answer useful please do not forget to accept it or up vote using the "Arrow" or "Tick" icons on the left side of my answer. Thanks :)